# Media Recorder start failed in android for front camera for Samsung Galaxy s3

Tags: java, android, camera

I am working on video recording app in which i want to display preview and when user click on record button it start recording and when user click stop button it stop recording.

I got camera preview and recording back camera is working fine.

But when I flip camera to front camera and when I start recording it occurs error like this:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed. 
        at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method) at 
        com.opkix.app.fragments.CameraFragment.startRecording(
                                             CameraFragment.java:104)
```

Here's my code for recording video code:

```
private boolean prepareMediaRecorder() {
    // set the orientation here to enable portrait recording.

    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    mCamera.unlock();

    mediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));


    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(StorageUtils.getOutputMediaFilePath());
    mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(120000); // Set max duration 60 sec.
    mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(100000000); // Set max file size 50Mb

    mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface());
    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

Can anyone please suggest solution?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10496969/1553851) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11249642/1553851).

Comment: also use some other method in your app.which is helpful on Video recording according to your App..[e.g. release camera & media recorder].because without use of that method Recording will crash your App.

Comment: @shmosel Hello, I already tried those solutions but those are for both back and front camera, but I'm facing only for front camera. could you please suggest me better solution?

Comment: Check this for same as your issue of @Semo.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474330/mediarecorder-problems-on-starting-video-capturing-on-android?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

now, i am also working on Video Recording App.Please one time Run your Code in some another device's.also i am sharing my Code with you.in which some of code is my App related code.remove that if you don't need that.

**My Code :**

```
private boolean prepareVideoRecorder() {
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    // Both are required for Portrait Video
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    if (mCameraId == CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        mRecorder.setOrientationHint(270);
    } else {
        mRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);
    }

    // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
    mCamera.unlock();
    mRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

    // Step 2: Set sources
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
    mRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);

    // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
    mRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P));

    // Step 4: Set output file
    final File folder;
    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/CameraApp/Videos");
    } else {
        folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/CameraApp/Videos");
    }

    boolean success = true;
    File videoFile;
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        success = folder.mkdirs();
    }
    if (success) {
        videoFile = new File(folder.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + getFileNameCustomFormat() + " " + ".mp4");

        SavedVideoPath = getFileNameCustomFormat() + " " + ".mp4";
        Log.e("Video Path - ", SavedVideoPath);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Video Not saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(String.valueOf(videoFile));

    // mRecorder.setVideoSize(mPreviewWidth, mPreviewHeight);

    // Step 5: Set the preview output
    mRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder.getSurface());

    // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "prepareVideoRecorder() Exception: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "prepareVideoRecorder() Exception: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And let me know what happen.? after trying my code.
Hope this will Helps :

Comment: Hello, I tried your code and same error happens. and sorry but I don't see any main difference between your code and my code.

Comment: in which device you did run.?

Comment: Samsung Galxay s3

Comment: you did check....this issue is for device issue or not...Run your App in some other device..may be this is the device Problem

Comment: oh, I checked with another device and it worked fine. sorry for that, btw could you please help me with that problem?

Comment: First of all bro.No sorry...i am always happy to others.

Comment: Please Use CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW. One type and check again in your Samsung Gal. S3

Comment: i Read this from Here :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681703/android-cant-record-video-with-front-facing-camera-mediarecorder-start-failed

Comment: but Remember....in some samsung device this problem [Camera Related] will occurs.
Because i am also developing an Camera App and i have also Passed through this Probelm...(:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132774/discussion-between-frank-lindstrom-and-sagar-aghara).